# Using Singletons in Objective-C

Tags: ios, singleton

There are a lot of people like me who are using sites like this (and others) to teach them selves iOS and Xcode. There is a lot of information out there and between that and the books I have bought I have learned a lot and am nearly finished with my first app. I need to have access to four NSMutableArrays to pass information from one UIViewController to another to display in a UITableView.

The problem is the information on Singletons ( and global variables in appDelegate ) is varied and confusing for a strugling programer. Where can I find clear, accurate and complete information on these two ways of sharing information within an app and across UIView controllers?

Thanks.

Comment: You have four arrays you want to pass from one view controller to another; what do you imagine that has to do with singletons? What do you think a singleton is?

Comment: I think the point is to avoid passing the array to every vc. Instead he's looking for a convenient way to make them accessible 'app-wide'. Despite the fact that it's not the best way to pass the data, a singleton is a valid way to achieve this.

Comment: No it isn't, @Tobi. The way to pass data from instance 1 to instance 2 is to pass it (i.e. at a time when instance 1 and instance 2 can see each other). Everyone can see the app delegate, so if the app delegate has properties, everyone else can fetch them. Or, if one instance instantiates another, they can see each other and info can be passed. That has nothing to do with singletons. Singletons are for e.g. a class that must be instantiated only once in the app's lifetime.

Comment: I didn't say it was a good way. But you can definitely use a singleton for that purpose. By the way to access the app delegate from a class that has no direct reference to it you use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` which essentially makes use of the fact, that the application object is implemented as a singleton.

Comment: No. It makes user of the fact that the application object is implemented as a global (i.e. it's available from anywhere thru a class method). Both UIApplication and the app delegate class are in fact singletons but that has nothing to do with what the original questioner wants to do. By saying "singleton" over and over you're just confusing him more than he is already.

Answer (score 2):

(First of all I do feel obligated to point out, that that isn't the way you should use to make data available in multiple view controllers.)

There are no global variables in Objective-C. At least not 'app-wide'. You can declare a 'file-wide' variable by:

```
static NSArray *_array;
```

But you can only access it within the same file. To make it accessible in other classes you have to create class methods to do this (at least as far as I know):

```
+ (NSArray *)array
{
    return array;
}

+ (void)setArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    _array = array;
}
```

(Of course you also need to declare the class methods in the header file.

The singleton pattern can be implemented like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject 

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *array; 

+(SomeClass*)sharedInstance;    

@end  



@implementation SomeClass    

static SomeClass *instance =nil;    
+(SomeClass *)sharedInstance    
{    
    @synchronized(self)    
    {    
        if(instance == nil)    
        {    
            instance= [[SomeClass alloc] init];    
        }    
    }    
    return instance;    
}
```

You could then access the array by calling:

```
[[SomeClass] sharedInstance].array
```

Comment: …and if you leave out the `static` in your `static NSArray *array;` it will be globally accessible. So I don't get what you mean by “no global variables in Objective-C”.

Comment: Don't you have to create a static variable and then access it via a class method?

Comment: Put the `NSArray *array;` in the `.m` file _outside_ of any class, e.g., before `@implementation`, then use the declaration `extern NSArray *array;` in other files where you wish to use it (e.g., by putting that in a header you include). Just like (non-objective-)C.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, but I saw those `extern` declarations in some of apple's header files before, wondering what it was :) Thx for the info.

Answer (score 0):

you may use both static (as in another answer) or "singleton" declarations, it'll do the job. This is not real singleton, but it acts as such:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSArray* arr1 = app.arr1;
if(!arr1) {
    // .. init the arr1 here
    NSArray* tmp = ...
    app.arr1 = tmp;
}
```

Of course it would be better to override `setArr1` method in the AppDelegate itself, but well, it depends.